# C# Get specific component from list of Components

Tags: c#, components

I have a List of Components

```
List<Component> components = new List<Component>();
```

I am designing a dynamic forms framework. I know that casting to a specific component is impossible even if I know what kind of component each of them is. How can I get the component as a specific type (for example `TextBox`, `ComboBox`) in order to use their properties.

For example I know that the first item of `components` is a `ComboBox`.
Can I get it as `ComboBox` in order to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
var textBoxes = components.OfType<TextBox>();
```